# Concatenating strings inside a PowerShell array

Tags: powershell

I want to use PowerShell to automate diskpart.exe, but the script arguments that PowerShell builds are seen as invalid. For example, the trivial diskpart script below works as expected:

```
$diskDetailsDPCom=@(
    "select disk 0",
    "detail disk",
    "exit"
)
$diskDetailsDPCom | diskpart
```

But when I try to build the “select disk” command by concatenating a variable or literal “0”, then diskpart fails with `The arguments specified for this command are not valid.`:

```
$diskDetailsDPCom=@(
    "select disk " + "0",
    "detail disk",
    "exit"
)
$diskDetailsDPCom | diskpart
```

What is going on here, and how might I proceed?

Comment: `"select disk " + “0”` -> `("select disk " + “0”)`

Comment: Some of those quotes are MS-Word's "smart quotes".  Is that intentional?

Comment: Smart quotes were due to a new Word install, and lazyness. Thanks again!

Comment: Not to worry. PowerShell understands smart quotes just fine, but they do break a lot of other command-line programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell the comma (`,`) operator has higher precedence than the concatenation (`+`) operator.  Your two blocks of code are evaluating differently.

```
@("select disk 0", “detail disk”, “exit”)
```

evaluates to an array with three strings as you expect.  However, your second example actually parses as

```
@("select disk " + (“0”, “detail disk”, “exit”))
```

To do the concatenation, PowerShell converts the array to a string with the `-join` operator, and your result is a string `"select disk 0 detail disk exit"`, wrapped in an array.

To get the array you want, put parentheses around the concatenation.

```
@(
    ("select disk " + “0”),
    “detail disk”,
    “exit”
)
```

Comment: That was my problem.Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Amended script. The splatting won't work but the array part should still be correct, as per @ryan bemrose's answer

```
$diskDetailsDPCom=@(
    "select disk", "0"
    , "detail disk"
   , "exit"
)
@diskDetailsDPCom | diskpart
```

Non-working answer below.

Instead of piping the args into `diskpart` try this...

```
$diskDetailsDPCom=@(
    "select disk", "0"
    , "detail disk"
   , "exit"
)
diskpart @diskDetailsDPCom
```

...where PowerShell will splat the array of args against `diskpart`.

Note that any args that need spaces between them are separate array elements. If using a switch such as `assign letter=R`, `letter=R` would be one array element.

This is untested against diskpart, but I have successfully used this method of splatting an array of args on the *left hand side* of an external command, rather than piping in and it works.

Comment: Sorry, diskpart is old and weird, and it does not take command-line arguments, it runs "scripts". So commands must be piped in. I tried your suggestion, and diskpart "was unable to process the parameters"